# Как получить время 5, 10, 20 или 30 минут назад?

Tags: php

Не могу найти в доках и гугле - как получить время 5, 10, 20 или 30 минут  назад?

Comment: Для этого не нужны доки. Нужно взять текущее время и отнять.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *А используя new DateTime?*

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');

$d = new DateTime;

echo $d->modify('-5 minutes')->format('H:i:s');
```

И т.д., по аналогу с "-5 minutes" установите интервал.

---

Или так:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');

echo (new DateTime('-5 minutes'))->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

Как то так

```
echo date("H:i", strtotime('-5 minutes',time()));
echo date("H:i", strtotime('-10 minutes',time()));
echo date("H:i", strtotime('-20 minutes',time()));
echo date("H:i", strtotime('-30 minutes',time()));
```

Comment: А используя `new DateTime`? Например:  `$objDate = new DateTime('now');`

Comment: @sterx  _time()_ итак по умолчанию передан: `date("H:i", strtotime('-5 minutes'));`

Comment: как то так

    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimestamp(time()-(60*5)); //5 or 10 or 20 or 30 minutes
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Офигеть, а чем `$objDate = new DateTime('-20 minutes');` не угодил?